# The metric spaces and nonexpansive maps: no non-empty space is finitelly presentable

Tags: metric-spaces, category-theory, limits-colimits, locally-presentable-categories

I have asked this question elsewhere, but I wrongly formulated it. Let me now correct it.
Why is no nonempty metric space in the category of metric spaces and non-expansive maps
finitely presentable ?
I got this hint:
Let in the category $\operatorname{ Met}$ of the metric spaces and non-expansive maps
be the diagram with a sequence of $2$ elements approaching with the distance $\frac{1}{n}$.

First: why there is a unique point in the colimit ?

Second: where have we used that the maps are non-expansive in the essential uniqueness of the factorization; why this doesn't hold for continuous maps or even arbitrary functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $X_n = \{a_n, b_n\}$ be the metric space with two points with distance $\frac{1}{n}$. For $n \leq m$ we have the obvious map $f_{nm}: X_n \to X_m$ given by $f_{nm}(a_n) = a_m$ and $f_{nm}(b_n) = b_m$. With these maps $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ forms a directed diagram. Let $X = \{*\}$ be the one-point space, then it clearly forms a cocone of this diagram. We claim that $X = \operatorname{colim}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$. Let $(g_n: X_n \to Y)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be any other cocone. Then it being a cocone implies directly that $g_n(a_n) = g_m(a_m)$ for all $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, and similar for the $b_n$. So we only need to show that $g_1(a_1) = g_1(b_1)$. This is where the choice of maps comes in, using that each $g_n$ is non-expansive we have for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that:
$$
d(g_1(a_1), g_1(b_1)) =
d(g_n(a_n), g_n(b_n)) \leq
d(a_n, b_n) = \frac{1}{n}
$$
So we must have that $d(g_1(a_1), g_1(b_1)) = 0$ and thus $g_1(a_1) = g_1(b_1)$.

Now let's finish the argument. Let $Z$ be any non-empty metric space. There is a (unique) map $h: Z \to X$ with constant value $*$. This map factors through the diagram, but not essentially uniquely. To see this, consider the constant map $h_1: Z \to X_1$ with value $a_1$, and the constant map $h'_1: Z \to X_1$ with value $b_1$. Both of these give factorisations of $h$. Since $Z$ is non-empty, these are different maps and there is no $f_{1n}: X_1 \to X_n$ such that $f_{1n} h_1 = f_{1n} h'_1$.

So the only place where non-expansiveness was used, was in the calculation of the colimit. If we allow any (continuous) function then there is, up to isomorphism, a unique two-point space. In particular, every map $f_{nm}: X_n \to X_m$ is an isomorphism. So the colimit of $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is just the two-point space again.

Comment: Dear Mark what is the distance of the $2$ points in your last line of the reply: "colimit of $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is just the two-point space" ?

Comment: @user122424 That doesn't matter. The point is that once you allow all continuous functions, then all two-point metric spaces are isomorphic. This is what I meant by "there is, up to isomorphism, a unique two-point space".

Comment: Right. And what is $X_n$ in this thing: $f_{1n}: X_1 \to X_n$ what does it tell that $f_{1n}$ doesn't exist ?

Comment: @user122424 The $X_n$ is still as I defined before, one of the objects in the diagram. So $f_{1n}: X_1 \to X_n$ is just one of the maps $f_{nm}$ I talked about before (maybe with poor choice of letters, $1$ now in the role of $n$ and $n$ in the role of $m$). Now use the fact that $Z$ is non-empty to show that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $f_{1n} h_1 \neq f_{1n} h'_1$. We are just directly checking the definition of 'essentially uniquely'.

Comment: I have a final question, why "Then it being a cocone implies directly that $g_n(a_n) = g_m(a_m)$ for all $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ " ?

Comment: @user122424 $g_1(a_1) =g_n  f_{1n}(a_1)=g_n(a_n)$ for all $n$, where the first equality follows from being a cocone and the second equality is the definition of $f_{1n}$.